# Is there a difference between using my router as a dns server or setting it directly on my pc?

Tags: networking, router, dns, pfsense

I have pfsense.

On pfsense my dns is set to 8.8.8.8.

Right now, on my computer my dns is set to 10.12.1.1 which is the gateway for my router.

Is there any difference between setting the DNS on my pc as 8.8.8.8 vs setting it as 10.12.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that setting it to your router means it'll get the DNS settings from that. As such, if you change the DNS server on the router, you won't have to go around manually changing it on any machines.

If you're using the same DNS server details on both, you may as well let the router handle this, as if you decide to change it later on it'll be a little less hassle to do so. Really though, it isn't making any difference.